# How to change the background color of the box in tkinter (python)

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, background

I am new to the python language, and I have been learning tkinter. However I wonder how can I change the background of the box that pops up in tkinter.

```
import time
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import sys
import os
root = tkinter.Tk()
```

Using this you get a grey box that pops up. How to I change the color of that box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Configure the root:

```
root.configure(background='red')
```

You can also directly assign it to the `bg` property:

```
root['bg'] = 'red'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 4):

```
root.configure(background='black')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)